# Angular (1) pagination for pages with a lot of large images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, pagination

I have a page who shows a lot of large images, when the user click the next button, I get from an array the next batch of big images. How can I load the next page of images (that are taken from google cloud storage) before clicking the next page button?
Currently the next page load very slowly because angular waits all the images to be loaded.

Example code:

controller function:

```
$scope.nextImage = function() {   
  $scope.index += 1;
  $scope.images = images[$scope.index]
}
```

html:

```
<img ng-src="images[0]" />
<img ng-src="images[1]" />
<img ng-src="images[2]" />
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to preload the list of your next images right after your set up current one

```
$scope.nextImage = function() {   
  $scope.index += 1;
  $scope.images = images[$scope.index];
  if($scope.index < MAX_IMAGE_LIST_COUNT) {      
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    preload(images[$scope.index + 1]);
  }
}
```

Where `preload()` is something like (based on [this](https://www.photo-mark.com/notes/image-preloading/), but you may search for some other way)

```
function preload(imageArray, index) {
  index = index || 0;
  if (imageArray && imageArray.length > index) {
    var img = new Image ();
    img.onload = function() {
        preload(imageArray, index + 1);
    }
    img.src = images[$scope.index + 1][index];
    return;
  }
  $scope.isLoading = false;
}
```

I also added the `isLoading` flag to watch the load procces.